# Grid panel vertical scrollbar issue after refresh

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs5

We are having a grid panel which refreshes every 20 seconds (`getView().refresh()`).

After refresh, the scrollbar loses position and the screen moves up and down. Also, a blank screen is displayed whenever the scrollbar is used and if the refresh happens at the same time. This is happening in both IE and Firefox.

Cellediting plugin is turned on in the grid panel.

Tried different options like preserveScrollerOnRefresh, listeners on beforerefresh, refresh to maintain scroll position, Ext.empty function...etc, but nothing seems to work.
Can anyone please reply on this?

Comment: Check this discussion once.Did you do it in the same way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647095/extjs-4-1-page-scrolls-to-top-of-grid-in-internet-explorer-on-row-update

Answer (score 0):

I tried this option but didn't work. I get a blank screen on scroll during refresh or the scrollbar jumps to any position after refresh

Comment: (You can delete this answer and add it as a comment)